# How to solve an error about incompatible types?

Tags: java, try-catch

I work on Intellij about Java project. Then I take an error in my try catch block about incompatible types. Here part of my code:

```
try (HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "D:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\RBBNCaseManagementTool\\src\\home\\data.xls")))) {

            HSSFSheet filtersheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int cellnum = filtersheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            int lastRow = filtersheet.getLastRowNum();
            HSSFCell cellVal1;
            HSSFCell cellVal2;
            HSSFCell cellVal3;
```

[image]
Is there any way to solve this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HSSFWorkbook` class implements the `Workbook` interface.

In POI 4.x, the [`Workbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html) interface implements `AutoCloseable` and `Closeable`.

In POI 3.x from 3.11 onwards, the [`Workbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/3.17/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html) interface implements only`Closeable`.

(Prior to 3.11, `Workbook` apparently didn't even implement `Closeable`; see https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.11 and https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56537)

So, if you want to use *try with resources* to manage an `HSSFWorkbook` instance, the simple solution is to upgrade to POI 4.0 or later.

Comment: Thank you so much. After I download the POI 4.0 and using jars the errors weren't appaer.  You safe my life :) I worked on it arround 4 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Try with resource only work with marker interface Autocloseable if your class `HSSFWorkbook` doesn't implement it you will get this error.

Comment: Seems it is: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html. But it could be a question of POI versions...